# How to change this array into keys and values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array...

```php
[
 [
  [
    "name" => "Initials"
    "value" => "ROR"
  ],
  [
    "name" => "Awards"
    "value" => "Swimming"
  ],
],
[
  [
    "name" => "Initials"
    "value" => "NAL"
  ],
  [
    "name" => "Awards"
    "value" => "Cycling"
  ],
 ]
]
```

What's the best way for me to change this array so I can save it like this...

```php
[
  [
    "Initials" => "ROR"
    "Awards" => "Swimming"
  ],
  [
    "Initials" => "NAL"
    "Awards" => "Cycling"
  ],
]
```

I've started doing something like looping through them and this... but this gives me one array element per new array.

```php
foreach($array as $rows) {
    foreach($rows as $field) {
        $values[] = [$field['name'] => $field['value']];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array_column()` to index the inner array, specifying the column to use as the value and the one to index it by...

```
$values = [];

foreach($array as $rows) {
    $values[] = array_column($rows, "value", "name");
}
print_r($values);
```

gives...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Initials] => ROR
            [Awards] => Swimming
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Initials] => NAL
            [Awards] => Cycling
        )

)
```

Comment: Perfect! I had tried array_column but I guess I was using it wrong. This works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
foreach($array as $rows) {
    foreach($rows as $field) {
        $values[] = [$field];
    }
}
```

or just you can use

```
$newArray = $array[0];
```